# Не работают импорты в проекте в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некоторая структура приложения

```
app
--controllers
--models
--routers
--main.py
--__init__.py
```

Во всех папках лежат пустые `__init__.py` и какие то модули

Так в чем проблема?

Каждый импорт "сверху" сопровождается такими вот ошибками

```
$poetry run python app/main.py -m

    ...немного текста о том, где ошибка...
    from ..models.fs_entity import FsEntity, FolderModel, FileModel
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Так вот, как это фиксить в рамках функционала питона? Без костылей в виде `sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('.'))` (это ведь костыль, так?)

,

p.s. питон у меня 3.10.9, модули должны по-идее работать =/

Comment: При запуске с ключом -m нужно указывать имя модуля как при импорте (имена через точку), а не путь (со слешами и расширением файла): `poetry run python -m app.main`

Comment: @insolor попробовал, теперь уже не видит модули при импорте:
`from routes.routes import router |||
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routes'`

Comment: При абсолютном импорте нужно указывать имя начиная от общего пакета, т.е. от app: `from app.routes.routes import router`